# Open an app (anyDesk) from the kubuntu 22.04 start menu as root (sudo)

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, anydesk

If I edit an app start menu icon, I cannot add "sudo" to the command field to request the sudo password. anyDesk can lock the cursor for the remote user if it is not opened as admin.

Seeing this error, I found a number of posts in the anyDesk help forum that the host needs to open anyDesk as admin.

https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/i-get-a-denied/forbidden-mouse-cursor-and-cannot-control-the-remote-computer
"In most cases, installing AnyDesk or launching it as an administrator on the remote endpoint can resolve the issue."

Answer (score 0):

You could try editing the `anydesk.desktop` file, which could be under `/usr/share/applications/` or you can use `locate anydesk.desktop` to find it.

Then add `sudo` after `Exec=`  and before the existing command.

Comment: Thank you. After adding sudo, it did come to a password popup. after entering the password for sudo, I get another password challenge, this one for root, which does not exist.